# Obtaining a reliable integer percentage ratio from two (64-bit) integers

Tags: c, 64-bit, int, computer-science

On my platform, `unsigned long long` is 64 bits (8 bytes). Suppose I have two such variables:

```
unsigned long long partialSize;
unsigned long long totalSize;
//somehow determine partialSize and totalSize
```

How can I reliably determine how many percentages (rounded to a nearby integer) `partialSize` is of `totalSize`? (If possible, it would be nice if I wouldn’t have to assume that the former is less than the latter, but if I really have to make this assumption, it’s fine. But we can, of course, assume that both are non-negative.)

For example, is the following code completely bulletproof? My fear is that it contains some kind of rounding, casting, or conversion errors that could cause the ratio to go out of whack under some conditions.

```
unsigned long long ratioPercentage
    = (unsigned long long)( ((double)partialSize)/((double)totalSize) * 100.0 );
```

Comment: You are correct that the straightforward method can "go out of whack" under very extreme cases. That's because there are two levels of rounding as well as a precision loss from 64-bits -> 53-bits.

Comment: @Mysticial. The result only need at most 7 bits of precision. I'd say 64 → 53 is not a problem at all.

Comment: Two links that might be of interest to you:  1) http://kanooth.com/numbers/  2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: @Mysticial: OP's formula is incorrect because it's always truncating towards 0, not rounding. `int((100 * 2751734980444983885.0) / 10006309019799941400.0 + 0.5)` gives me 28 in Python. I agree though there might be rare cases which the 64-bit result gives 0.49999... and the 53-bit result gives 0.5000...

Comment: @KennyTM I deleted my last comment because it was a bad example. Here's a better one: `850536266682995018 / 3335436339933313800` This one fails even with the `+0.5`. Correct answer is `25%`, the correct formula gives `26%`. But yes, we are in agreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not completely bullet-proof. `double` mantissae are only 53 bits (52 + 1 implicit), so if your numbers are larger than `2^53`, the conversion to `double` will in general introduce rounding errors. However, the rounding errors are very small in relation to the numbers itself, so a percentage calculation resulting in an integer value will introduce more inaccuracy than the conversion.

A possibly more serious concern is that this will always round downwards, e.g. for `totalSize = 1000` and `partialSize = 99`, it will return `9` rather than the closer value `10`. You can get better rounding by adding `0.5` before casting to `unsigned long long`.

You can get exact results using only integer arithmetic (if the final result doesn't overflow), it's fairly easy if `partialSize` is not too large:

```
if (partialSize <= ULLONG_MAX / 100) {
    unsigned long long a = partialSize * 100ULL;
    unsigned long long q = a / totalSize, r = a % totalSize;
    if (r == 0) return q;
    unsigned long long b = totalSize / r;
    switch(b) {
        case 1: return q+1;
        case 2: return totalSize % r ? q : q+1; // round half up
        default: return q;
    }
}
```

Easy modifications if you want floor, ceiling or round-half-to-even.

It's okay if `totalSize >= 100` and `ULLONG_MAX / 100 >= partialSize % totalSize`,

```
unsigned long long q0 = partialSize / totalSize;
unsigned long long r = partialSize % totalSize;
return 100*q0 + theAbove(r);
```

It gets more fiddly in the other cases, I'm not keen on doing it, but I could be persuaded if you need it.

Comment: +1. Although I haven't tested this, it looks viable and addresses the different rounding behaviors.

Comment: But for round-half-up and numbers without risk of overflow, yours is simpler and faster.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your formula isn't correct as it omits the `+0.5` needed to get round-to-nearest.

So I'll proceed assuming this corrected formula:

```
(unsigned long long)( ((double)partialSize)/((double)totalSize) * 100.0 + 0.5);
```

As I've mentioned in the comments, the straight-forward method, although simple, is not guaranteed to correctly rounded results. So your intuition is right in that it is not bullet-proof.

In the vast majority of cases, it will still be correct, but there will be a small set of borderline cases where it won't be correctly rounded. Whether or not those matter is up to you. But the straight-forward method is usually sufficient for most purposes.

**Why it may fail:**

There are 4 levels of rounding. (corrected from the 2 that I mentioned in the comments)

1. The casts 64-bits -> 53-bits
2. The division
3. The multiply by 100.
4. The final cast.

Whenever you have multiple sources of rounding, you suffer from the usual sources of floating-point error.

**Counter Examples:**

Although rare, I'll list a few examples where the straight-forward formula will give an incorrectly rounded result:

```
 850536266682995018 /  3335436339933313800  //  Correct: 25%  Formula: 26%
3552239702028979196 / 10006309019799941400  //  Correct: 35%  Formula: 36%
1680850982666015624 /  2384185791015625000  //  Correct: 70%  Formula: 71%
```

**Solution:**

I can't think of a clean 100% bullet-proof solution to this other than to use [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

***But in the end, do you really need it to always be perfectly rounded?***

---

**EDIT :**

For smaller numbers, here's a very simple solution that rounds up on `0.5`:

```
return (x * 100 + y/2) / y;
```

This will work as long as `x * 100 + y/2` doesn't overflow.

@Daniel Fischer answer has a more comprehensive solution for the other rounding behaviors. Though it shouldn't be too hard to modify this one to get round-to-even.

Comment: What if I know all of my numbers to be less than 2^53? Will I get accurate results then? (I’m dealing with file sizes, and in my case files won’t get that humongous.)

Comment: If your numbers are less than 2^53, that eliminates point 1. I'm rather confident that one can still find a few cases where the floating point rounding pushes the result across the 0.5 (or integer) boundary, but is a wrongly rounded result for a percentage of `xx.5 ± epsilon` a real problem? If it is, the integer method I added to my answer would guarantee correctly rounded results since overflow is not an issue here.

Comment: The +0.5 looks like a hack. What about this instead?-> `static unsigned int d(unsigned long long p, unsigned long long t) { return round((double)p * 100 / t); }`

Comment: @jørgensen It's almost the same. Probably a bit cleaner, but it still suffers from the same round-off errors that would break the original method.

Answer (score 2):

A single formula will always overflow, crash or give large mistakes for some values.
This combination works well almost always:

```
if (totalSize > 1000000) {
    pct = partialSize / (totalSize / 100);
} else {
    pct = (partialSize*100) / totalSize;
}
```

It will only fail when partialSize is larger than MAX_U_LONG_LONG/100, and totalSize is below 1000000. In this case, the correct percentage is much larger than 100%, so it isn't very interesting.

Comment: Great advice.  But you're missing the bias: this will truncate towards zero instead of rounding.

Comment: Indeed, this code doesn't truncate exactly right. Worse, the partialSize/(totalSize/100) logic loses some percision, so it can miss by some more. But the question says "rounded to a nearby integer", not nearest.